# Getting full list of authors after first citation with biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

The APA style requires that the first citation for 3 to 6(?) authors uses the full list of authors while subsequent citations use an abbreviated list of authors. This is implemented by `biblatex-apa`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

% full author list
\parencite{herrmann}

% abbreviated author list
\parencite{herrmann}

% I would like a full author list here
\parencite{herrmann}

% this should be abbreviated again
\parencite{herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

In some cases it would be interesting to get the full list of authors even in a subsequent citation. Is that possible? The ideal solution would be a switch that would cause all subsequent citations to be treated as first ones, so that only the second citation after the "switch" would be abbreviated.

This question is motivated by a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57348859/8416610) where a user tries to do something like this in the context of `csl` and `pandoc-citeproc`. I have the hope that a `biblatex` based workflow is more flexible.

Comment: Would you want this for all citations or just for a particular `.bib` entry? Also,   I'm not sure I understand the "so that..." part of your ideal solution.

Comment: @AlanMunn The ideal solution would affect for all citations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` uses the test `\ifciteseen` to check if a citation should use the long or short form. This tracker can be reset completely with `\citereset`. `biblatex-apa` also defines an additional special tracker which can be reset with `\citeresetapa` (this tracker is only used in very special circumstances with `shortauthor`/`shorteditor` fields, so forgetting to reset it will do almost no harm in most use cases).

So if you issue

```
\citereset\citeresetapa
```

anywhere in your document all first citations after that line will use the long form and subsequent citations will be short again. This affects all entries alike.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

% full author list
\parencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

% abbreviated author list
\parencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

% I would like a full author list here
\citereset\citeresetapa
\parencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

% this should be abbreviated again
\parencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Herrmann, Öfele, Schneider, Herdtweck, & Hoffmann, 2006)//(Yoon, Ryu, Kim, & Ahn, 2006)//(Herrmann et al., 2006)//(Yoon et al., 2006)//(Herrmann, Öfele, Schneider, Herdtweck, & Hoffmann, 2006)//(Yoon, Ryu, Kim, & Ahn, 2006)//(Herrmann et al., 2006)//(Yoon et al., 2006)]

The load-time package option `citereset=<section level>` lets you automatically execute `\citereset` at all headings of `<section level>`. So `citereset=section` would call `\citereset` at each `\section`. There is no analogous option for `\citeresetapa`.

---

If you only want to affect a particular citation, something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\longparencite}{%
  \AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{%
    \let\blx@imc@ifciteseen\@secondoftwo
    \let\ifciteseen\blx@imc@ifciteseen}}%
  \parencite}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% full author list
\parencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

% abbreviated author list
\parencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

% I would like a full author list here
\longparencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

% this should be abbreviated again
\parencite{herrmann}

\parencite{yoon}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

might work better for you.

[image: (Herrmann, Öfele, Schneider, Herdtweck, & Hoffmann, 2006)//(Yoon, Ryu, Kim, & Ahn, 2006)//(Herrmann et al., 2006)//(Yoon et al., 2006)//(Herrmann, Öfele, Schneider, Herdtweck, & Hoffmann, 2006)//(Yoon et al., 2006)//(Herrmann et al., 2006)//(Yoon et al., 2006)]

With this definition `\longparencite` locally pretends that the citation was not seen before, hence we get the long form. `\longparencite` does not affect other citations and at least with this definition `\longparencite` does count towards `\ifciteseen` in situations like `\longparencite{herrmann}\parencite{herrmann}` (that could be changed of course).

Comment: Thanks. `citereset=chapter` is perfect.